# How to find two GrepPreference in InDesign using javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Is there a way to find two options using the app.findGrepPreferences in InDesign JavaScript?

For example how to find all SmallCaps text that is underlined and italic?
I only know the code to find small caps, which is :

```
app.findGrepPreferences.capitalization = Capitalization.smallCaps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set these options one by one and then do the search. For a reference of the option properties see the `findGrepPreferences` class [reference](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#FindGrepPreference.html).

This should do what you are asking for:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

app.findGrepPreferences.capitalization = Capitalization.SMALL_CAPS;
app.findGrepPreferences.underline = true;
app.findGrepPreferences.fontStyle = "Italic";

var results = doc.findGrep();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

app.findGrepPreferences.properties = {
  capitalization: Capitalization.SMALL_CAPS,
  underline: true, 
  fontStyle: "Italic"
};

var results = doc.findGrep();
```